# Clear Memory when using PictureBox Control

Tags: vb.net, memory, picturebox

I have a TreeView and when you click on a node, the code gets the tag of the node and then displays a picture in a PictureBox Control. After clicking through so many of them, I get a Console Message:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
```

After that no more pictures will load in the PictureBox. I have tried using Dispose on the PictureBox before the new image loads but then the image doesn't show up in the PictureBox. The code below is all I am using for this.

```
pbMainTools.Image = Image.FromFile(strImagePath & ".jpg")
```

I am also getting the path to the image from a DataTable using the tag from the node:

```
For Each NewTool As DataRow In NTDS.Tools.Select("ToolID = " & tvTag)
     strImagePath = NewTool.Item("Image")
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `PictureBox.Dispose()` then you'll dispose of the ***entire control***, making it unusable (hence why you couldn't show the image). To dispose the image only, do:

```
pbMainTools.Image.Dispose()
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily stop the application from throwing an `OutOfMemoryException`, because one reason could be that the image is too large for GDI+ to load into memory.

Comment: Well all the images display fine, it is only after clicking on so many that it happens. So I was assuming that it is keeping every image in memory when you load it.

Comment: @xRuhRohx : Yes, I understood that. I just pointed out that an `OutOfMemoryException` can be caused by other problems as well, so you know that in case `PictureBox.Image.Dispose()` doesn't work (which I take it didn't?).

Comment: This particular batch of photos I forgot to resize before adding them to the application. I shrunk them down and now there is no issue. So you suggesting the image was too large made me remember I had forgotten to do so. They were like 5000x4000 when all the others are 1400x1050.

Comment: @xRuhRohx : Well sometimes one forgets the simple things ;). Glad I could help!